# HttpResponseError: Operation returned an invalid status 'Forbidden'

Tags: azure, jupyter-notebook, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault, azure-app-configuration

I am running a function in Jupyter notebook to test my connection to a Database

Here is the code:

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.appconfiguration import AzureAppConfigurationClient
from azure.keyvault.secrets import SecretClient
import requests


config_url = '#####'
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()


app_slug = 'XXXXX' 
key = '*******' 
label=None

key = '{}:{}'.format(app_slug, key)

config_client = AzureAppConfigurationClient(base_url=config_url, credential=credential)

fetched_config = config_client.get_configuration_setting(key=key, label=label)

fetched_config.value
```

It will connect for a coworker but not mine. I am wondering if anyone has run into this problem before and could help

The error seems to be in this line:
`fetched_config = config_client.get_configuration_setting(key=key, label=label)`
but I cannot understand why

Comment: what is your role at the app configuration level ? you need some permissions in order to read configuration.

Comment: I am the Owner of the app configuration, not sure why it is working for others but not me

Comment: could you share the error message with us ?

Comment: /distpackages/azure/appconfiguration/_azure_appconfiguration_client.py:246, in AzureAppConfigurationClient.get_configuration_setting(self, key, label, etag, match_condition, **kwargs)
246     key_value = self._impl.get_key_value(
247         key=key,
248         label=label,
249         if_match=prep_if_match(etag, match_condition),
250         if_none_match=prep_if_none_match(etag, match_condition),
251         error_map=error_map,
252         **kwargs )
253     return ConfigurationSetting._from_key_value(key_value)
ErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status 'Forbidden'

Comment: Forbidden is most likely related to networking / fiewall rule. is your app config service configured with some networking restriction ?